# How to share the same ViewModel with ViewPager, Navigation and Hilt?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation

I'm trying to use the same ViewHolder between this fragments.

FragmentA, FragmentB and Fragment E are in a navGraph, Fragment C and D are not.

I tried using `by viewModels()` but it initialized the ViewModel 3 times (on A, C, E)

Using `by activityViewModels()` it initilized the ViewModel 2 times (on A and C)

I also tried `by viewModels(ownerProducer = {requireParentFragment().requireParentFragment()})` in Fragment C and D but it keeps initializing the ViewModel.

And the last thing i tried is inserting Fragment A, B and E into a navGraph and using
`by navGraphViewModels(R.id.customNavGraph) { defaultViewModelProviderFactory }` but got the same result as above.

In conclusion, Fragment C and D keep initializing the ViewModel

How can i fix this?

[image]

Comment: use `viewModelProviders()` and pass the original activity or the first navGraph back stack entry as the viewmodel store owner, or you could implement a custom ViewModelStoreOwner with somehow a global access and store the viewModel in that. see the fragment code or activity's code to see how to implement a ViewModelStoreOwner

Comment: Hello... we have a solution for this question using hilt?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried accessing the viewModels extension function on `requireParentFragment()`. And to ensure that the viewModel is called after the child fragment is attached to the parent/host, you can initialize it lazily or just initialize it after the fragment is attached to the parent

```
private val viewModel by lazy { requireParentFragment().viewModels<YourViewModel>() }
```